# Best approach to hosting a .NET console app on AWS that runs on a schedule?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

I have a .NET Core console app that needs to run once every few hours. This console app calls a third party API and inserts some records into a database.

The bulk of my experience lies with Azure, where I would have implemented this as an [App Service WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create). However my team has now switched over to AWS which I'm not too familiar with.

What would be the best way to host this console app on AWS without having to spin up an entire EC2/VM just for one scheduled task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Lambda custom runtime, which supports .Net Core 3.0

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/

In AWS you can schedule Lambdas with a CloudWatch Event Rule. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html